# Missing hermit crabs?

Tags: aquarium, lost-pet

My little hermit crab joy has abandoned her shell last night and I have no idea where she is. I have no idea what happened and my other crabs look fine. She has never done anything like this before and she is usually active around the tank. She did disappear under the substrate for a day a couple days ago but she quickly reappeared with her shell ON the whole time. I'm just worried that she died because my other crab teensy died the same way. She abandoned her shell and never returned. I'm scared for joy because she was one of my favorites and always enjoyed to play with me.

Comment: Do you have additional shells for them to use? Hermit crabs grow and must upgrade shells as they grow. If you do not have replacement shells of varying sizes for them to use (obviously larger ones must be offered), they often are eaten by other crabs or perish as they cannot find suitable protection and may not eat or come out from hiding.